# Liftweb: how to execute a "scala" method after ajaxText submit

Tags: ajax, scala, lift, onsubmit

I know that I can run a script submitting an ajaxText this way:

```scala
SHtml.ajaxText(myVar, (str) => myVar = str, "onsubmit" -> "myScript();")
```

What I would like to do is to execute a scala method instead.

Obviously

```scala
SHtml.ajaxText(myVar, (str) => myVar = str, "onsubmit" -> myMethod)
```

is not working.

Is there a way I can do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your answer looks fine to me, but if you don't want anything to happen after executing, you don't have to have the `JsCmd` do anything. For example:

```
SHtml.ajaxText(myVar, (str) => {
  myVar = str
  myMethod()
  JsCmds.Noop
})
```

Where the `JsCmds.Noop`, is pretty much the same as issuing `return` in plain JavaScript, so the function returns without doing anything. I put the codeblock inline for brevity, but you could also just do what you did with `(str) => f(str)` and have your method return `JsCmds.Noop`.

Comment: Glad I can be of continued assistance. As you have other questions, just ask and we'll do our best to help out.

Answer (score 1):

I found a way, but is not so clean.

since the function `(str) => myVar = str` is also executed on submit, that's what I've done:

```
def f(str:String):JsCmd = {
  myVar = str
  myMethod()
  SetHtml("msg_div",<span> method executed </span>)
}

SHtml.ajaxText(myVar, (str) => f(str))
```

This way every time I submit a modification in ajaxText `myMethod` is executed but I'm forced to return some `JsCmd` from the `f` function.

If you find a better way to do that let me know please.

Comment: By the way, you can shorten `(str) => f(str)` to `str => f(str)` to just plan `f _`. (Actually you may not even need the `_`. You certainly won't need it if you write `def` (or `val`) `f = { str: String =>` ...